# Changing elements on a page into user controls

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views

So I want to change the different table and div elements on my page to be user controls so I can then render them as a partial view instead of having an extremely cluttered front end.

One example would be this table:

```
<table id="summaryInformation" class="resultsGrid" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td id="EffectiveDateLabel" class="resultsCell">
                        <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.EffectiveDate) %>
                    </td>
                    <td id="EffectiveDateValue" class="alignRight">
                        <%= Model.EffectiveDate.Value.ToString(Chatham.Web.Data.Constants.Format.DateFormatString) %>
                    </td>
                    <td id ="NotionalLabel" class="resultsCell">
                        <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.Notional) %>
                    </td>
                    <td id="NotionalValue" class="alignRight">
                        <span>
                            <%= Chatham.Enumerations.CurrencyHelper.GetFriendlyName((Chatham.Enumerations.Currency)Model.FloatingComponent.CurrencyID.Value) %>
                        </span>
                        <%= Model.Notional.Value.ToString(Chatham.Web.Data.Constants.Format.CurrencyCentsIncludedFormatString) %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="MaturityDateLabel" class="resultsCell">
                        <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.MaturityDate) %>
                    </td>
                    <td id="MaturityDateValue" class="alignRight">
                        <%= Model.MaturityDate.Value.ToString(Chatham.Web.Data.Constants.Format.DateFormatString)%>
                        -
                        <%= Model.AmortizationComponent.MaturityBusinessDayConvention%>
                    </td>
                        <td id="Td3" class="resultsCell"> Holiday City</td>
                        <td id="ddlHolidayCity" colspan="3">
                    <%for(int i = 0; i < Model.Trx.TransactionHolidayCityCollection.Count; i++){%><%=i > 0 ? "," : ""%>
                        <%=DropDownData.HolidayDays().ToList().Find(item => item.Value == Model.Trx.TransactionHolidayCityCollection[i].HolidayCityID.Value.ToString()).Text%><%}
                    %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                </tr>
                <tr >
                    <td id="TimeStampLabel" class="resultsCell">
                        Rate Time Stamp
                    </td>
                    <td id="Timestamp" class="alignRight">
                        <%= Model.StateBag.CurveDate.TimeStamp.ToString(Chatham.Web.Data.Constants.Format.DateTimeFormatString) %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

How would I change this into a user control and then how would I render this as a partial view in the front end?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Just took each `table` element and put it into its own .aspx file, importing the same files at the top, and then rendered them as partial views instead.